# Using nginx Ingress paths to redirect to multiple services

Tags: kubernetes, path, nginx-ingress

I have an Azure k8s cluster, in which I want to serve two services, Jenkins and my own node app. I have the docker images and they work properly. I need to access to **mydomain.com/jenkins** and see my Jenkins instance. The same applies to **mydomain.com/node** and my node app.

The first problem I faced is that I could see the html page, but for example the css tried to load in mydomain.com/css/style.css, not mydomain.com/node/css/style.css. I fixed it with my current ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(jenkins)?/?(.*)
        backend:
            serviceName: jenkins-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

This has been my closest attempt. With this config, I can succesfully access to Jenkins. But, if I add another path for my node app, even when I access **mydomain.com/node** it will redirect me to Jenkins. I know it would be a lot easier to do this with subdomains, but I have especifically been told to do it this way. I have been stuck with this all day, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: @hariK my kubernetes version is 1.15.10

Comment: Can you configure and try `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` and paths as `/jenkins` and `/node` ?

Comment: That won't work as expected, I already tried it.

Comment: Why are you using rewrite? Just use your host and add two `paths` for your jenkins backend and node backend.